Categoricity and the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem
Morley's categoricity theorem states:

If a first-order theory in a countable language is categorical in some uncountable cardinality, then it is categorical in all uncountable cardinalities.

As per the definition this only applies to uncountable cardinalities. But why doesn't the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem (assuming a countable language $L$) imply categoricity in all infinite cardinalities if a theory $T$ is $\kappa$-categorical, for $\kappa$ is some infinite cardinality?
An isomorphism $\pi\colon A\to B$ can be 'dumbed down' to 3 main points

$A$ and $B$ are elementary equivalent (for $\varphi\in L$ then $M\models \varphi \iff N\models \varphi$)
$A$ and $B$ have the same 'structure' ($n$-ary functions and $n$-ary relations are preserved)
|$A$| = |$B$|, they have the same cardinality

For a model $M\models T$, the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem guarantees there are elementary extensions of $M$, $M\preceq N$ and $M\preceq U$. If $|M| =|N|$, then doesn't this imply $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic as it satisfies the 3 checkboxes for isomorphic structures? So if $T$ has $1$ isomorphism class in an infinite cardinality, then it should have $1$ for all infinite cardinalities (otherwise, a contradiction will occur where it isn't categorical in any infinite cardinality)?
This link seems to support this: Spectrum of a theory.

The Löwenheim-Skolem theorem shows that if $I(T,\kappa)$ is nonzero for one infinite cardinal then it is nonzero for all of them.

Where $I(T,K)$ is the number of isomorphism classes.
This application of the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem must be wrong in some way, otherwise we wouldn't have a need for Morley's categoricity theorem and we wouldn't have theories that are $\omega$-categorical. My intuition tell me that $M\preceq N$ and $M\preceq U$ isn't enough to guarantee an isomorphism, even if $|M| =|N|$. Thus, we require the categoricity theorem (which I believe does some stuff with saturated models?)

Just consider a concrete example of a theory which is categorical in one infinite power but not another - say, DLOWE (dense linear orders without endpoints), with the models $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ ordered as usual.

@NoahSchweber Yes I'm aware that the theory of dense linear order without endpoints is countably categorical (but not in uncountable cardinalities). But I'm trying to understand this in the context of the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem.

My point is to try to trace through your argument with this example and see where it breaks down. You've essentially already got it: "My intuition tell me that M≼N and M≼U isn't enough to guarantee an isomorphism, even if |M| =|N|" is exactly right, and DLOWE shows why.

@NoahSchweber My guess is that the 'interpretation' of M in N and U are isomorphic, but that doesn't necessarily apply to the whole structure (after all for an embedding f: A -> B we say B has the same 'structure' of A restricted to the domain of A). Since N and U aren't necessarily isomorphic then that doesn't tell us anything about countable categoricity, so we have to rely on Morley's categoricity theorem. Is this right?

(a) Please use MathJax (see here) for formatting all mathematical symbols. (b) Avoid embedding images whenever possible, especially when the image just contains text that you could type out. I'll edit your question now to improve the formatting. Please take a look at the changes I made and keep them in mind for future posts.

You write:

An isomorphism $\pi\colon A\to B$ can be 'dumbed down' to 3 main
points

$A$ and $B$ are elementary equivalent (for $\varphi\in L$ then $M\models \varphi \iff N\models \varphi$)
$A$ and $B$ have the same 'structure' ($n$-ary functions and $n$-ary relations are preserved)
$A$ and $B$ are bijective


This "dumbed down" interpretation is imprecise and incorrect. I think it's giving you entirely the wrong intuition.
First: I don't know what is meant by "$A$ and $B$ are bijective". Bijectivity is a property of a function, not a pair of sets. If you mean that $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality, that's true whenever $A\cong B$. But in order for $\pi\colon A\to B$ to be an isomorphism, you need to know that $\pi$ itself is a bijection, not just that there exists some bijection between $A$ and $B$.
Similarly, the fact that $A$ and $B$ are elementarily equivalent is a consequence of $A\cong B$. But it is not part of the definition of isomorphism, and it is certainly not sufficient for $A\cong B$. It is possible to have structures $A$ and $B$ with $A\equiv B$ (elementarily equivalent) and $|A| = |B|$ (same cardinality), but $A\not\cong B$.
The correct definition is that $\pi\colon A\to B$ is an isomorphism if $\pi$ is a bijection $A\to B$ which preserves the function symbols in $L$ and preserves and reflects the relation symbols in $L$. This is what you need to check to show that two structures are isomorphic, not the "check boxes" you listed.
I have no idea why you think the quote from Wikipedia supports your idea. It just says that if $T$ (in a countable language!) has some infinite model, then it has infinite models of all infinite cardinalities. It does not say anything about isomorphisms between these models. (Put another way: It's saying $I(T,\kappa)\geq 1$, not $I(T,\kappa) = 1$.)
Moral: Don't try to "dumb down" mathematical concepts. Without precise definitions, you won't get anywhere.

At first the I did think the quote did support this for the following reasons. I wasn't worried about if the value of I(T,κ) = 1 or not, more so that the no. of Isomorphism classes remained the same throughout all infinite cardinalities (i.e., if I(T,k) is nonzero for an infinite cardinal then it is nonzero for all of them). This could then be used for a value of 1. Although, I have now realized that this is wrong and the Löwenheim–Skolem theorem only guarantees a no. of isomorphism classes for each infinite cardinality, not that the number is the same.

Another oversight on my part is that the interpretation of M in N and U have the same structure but this does not necessarily imply that N and U have the same structure. Thus, N≆U. Thank you for understanding.
